# Getting EC2 instance name inside a Chef recipe

Tags: amazon-web-services, chef-infra

How can I dynamically capture the ec2 instance name on which my Chef recipe is running?

@coderanger I am using below code

```
Ohai.plugin(:EC2) do 
provides "ec2" 
depends "ec2" collect_data do 
instance_id = ec2['instance_id'] 
end 
end
```

How to print the instance id here ?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean the EC2 instance ID, you can find it in `node['ec2']['instance_id']` if the EC2 ohai plugin has been activated. If the instance is created via `knife ec2 server create` this is done automatically for you, and there is an imperfect auto-enable that tries to guess if you're on EC2. If neither of these are the case, you can force it by creating an empty file in `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json`.

Comment: I am looking for instance name not instance id. Can you please guide

Comment: @Dave - I am dealing with the same issue right now.  The ec2 instance name is not a part of metadata, it is a tag.  Hence, you need to do a `aws ec2 describe-instances` on your instance and grab it from there.

Comment: Unfortunately there is no direct way to get tag data from the instance itself. You could use an IAM instance profile with permission to run the `describe-instance` API call and then use that but you can't restrict that to "only self" so every server will be able see every other server too, which may have security consequences. Amazon seems to consider tags to not be a part of their API overall, and should not be used for automation.

Comment: @coderanger 
I am using below code 

Ohai.plugin(:EC2) 
do provides "ec2" 
depends "ec2" collect_data do 
instance_id = ec2['instance_id'] 
end 
end 

How to print the instance id here ?

Comment: Comments don't retain formatting, please add the code in a block in your question.

Comment: For some reason adding the empty file `/etc/chef/ohai/hints/ec2.json` solves the issue. Good answer!